# Descriptor extractor causes error

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

i wrote the below code to do features matching for list of Mat objects, the problem is at run time i receive the below posted errors, as far as i understood it, i checked the extenstion and the size of the used image
and they are .jpg and 538*522 except one image is 538*520

is the image with different size might cause such error?
please help me to fix this issue.

**Code**:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    loadOpenCVLib();
                                    /*Step_1: Feature Detection*/
    initFeatureDetector();
                                    /*Step_2: Descriptor Extractor*/
    initDescriptorExtractor();
}

private static void initDescriptorExtractor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    descriptorsList = new ArrayList<Mat>();

    descriptorsList.add(new Mat());
    descriptorsList.add(new Mat());
    descriptorsList.add(new Mat());

    DescriptorExtractor descripExtractor = 
    DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SIFT);
    descripExtractor.compute(matList, keyPointsList, descriptorsList);
    //descripExtractor.write(fileName) test this method
    //descripExtractor.read(fileName)
}

private static void initFeatureDetector() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    matList = new ArrayList<Mat>();
    keyPointsList = new ArrayList<MatOfKeyPoint>();

    matList.add(path2Mat(path_jf00));
    matList.add(path2Mat(path_jf01));
    matList.add(path2Mat(path_jf02));

    keyPointsList.add(newMatKeyPoints());
    keyPointsList.add(newMatKeyPoints());
    keyPointsList.add(newMatKeyPoints());

    FeatureDetector featsDetect =    
    FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
    featsDetect.detect(matList, keyPointsList);
}

private static void loadOpenCVLib() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}

private static Mat path2Mat(String path2File) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Highgui.imread(path2File);
}

private static MatOfKeyPoint newMatKeyPoints() {
    return new MatOfKeyPoint();
}
```

}

**Error**:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (imageCollection.size() ==  
pointCollection.size()) in cv::DescriptorExtractor::compute, file 
 ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\features2d\src\descriptors.cpp, line 74

Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: 
cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\features2d
\src\descriptors.cpp:74: error: (-215) imageCollection.size() == 
pointCollection.size() in function cv::DescriptorExtractor::compute
]
 at org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor.compute_1(Native Method)
at 
 org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor.compute(DescriptorExtractor.java:140)
at test.FeatsMatch.initDescriptorExtractor(FeatsMatch.java:40)
at test.FeatsMatch.main(FeatsMatch.java:28)
```

Comment: Looks like there might be issue with your image list or key points list, the assertion: imageCollection.size() ==  
pointCollection.size() is failing. Try extracting descriptors using the first variant of compute (takes single mats instead of lists) and see what happens.

Comment: @user3510227 i have tried to pass the parameters stored in the list one by one instead of passing the whole list object and iti is working now..thanks